# List external domains used by webpage using ajax/php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I'm trying to get a list of external domains called by a webpage when loading the page by ajax.

I can load the page html and scan it for urls but this includes all links to external sites and misses out domains called by things like social widgets.

I have looked into api's like pagespeed and webpagetest but they don't return this information, only the number of external domains called.

Is there a way to load a page and analyse the headers to record the external domains called either by javascript alone or by calling a php function?

Something similar to the live http headers extension for firefox but minus the browser :)

Comment: Do you need this to be easily automated or just a quick script you can run when needed manually?

Comment: It's triggered by a button click which adds the results to a text area. The aim is a list of urls for dns-prefetching, this is really a helper/usability tweak. I started off scanning the page and only later realised the results are pretty much the opposite of what I need aside from a few domains picked from the doc head so looking for a better way to approach it.

Comment: well this seems impossible so I'm making a little webpage using phantomjs instead. I'll direct people there.